# Ansible - Add these 2 values to grub.conf

Tags: ansible

Add the following values to grub.conf

```
net.ifnames=0 audit=1
```

I can audit audt=1 with the following code, but I am having problems adding net.ifnames=0

```
name: Ensure auditing for processes that start prior to auditd is enabled"
  replace:
      dest: /etc/default/grub
      regexp: '(^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX\s*\=\s*)(?:")(.+)(?<!audit=1)(?:")'
      replace: '\1"\2 audit=1"'
      follow: yes
  ignore_errors: yes
```

Comment: What sort of problems are you having adding `net.ifnames`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below.

```
  - name: Ensure auditing for processes that start prior to auditd is enabled"
    replace:
      dest: /etc/default/grub
      regexp: '^(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=(?!.* audit)\"[^\"]+)(\".*)'
      replace: '\1 audit=1\2'
    ignore_errors: yes
  - name: Ensure auditing for processes that start prior to auditd is enabled"
    replace:
      dest: /etc/default/grub
      regexp: '^(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=(?!.* net.ifnames)\"[^\"]+)(\".*)'
      replace: '\1 net.ifnames=0\2'
    ignore_errors: yes
```

Comment: I have updated the answer , please try and let meknow